# How to use radgrid's FilterExpression with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, radgrid

I have a radgrid and when I filter, I get something like:

```
"(iif(Name== null, \"\",  Name).ToString().ToUpper().Contains(\"ap\".ToUpper()))"
```

In my Linq Data Source Selecting event, I would like to use this filter in my results by doing something like results = results.Where(FilterExression), but this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've used:

```
var filterExpression = gridOrderLineItems.MasterTableView.FilterExpression;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterExpression))
   allItems = allItems.AsQueryable()
              .Where(filterExpression)
              .ToList();
```

As you can see from Telerik documentation, there are two filter modes in RadGrid. One is Lynq Dynamic and another one is SQL-like. I think the default is dynamic, provided that your datasource supports it. I had one case where the grid was using SQL syntax because the datasource was IEnumerable and I had to changed it to List in order to enable dynamic expression. You can see what mode the grid is in by simply checking FilterExpression property. There is EnableLinqExpressions property you can play with as well.

Comment: What a pain. Just stumbled across this. Adding `.ToList()` to my `IQueryable` collection changed the filterexpression from being SQL-like to LINQ-like. You sir, may have an upvote.

Comment: I dont see any overloads for the `Where` method which accept a string, are you sure this code is correct?

Comment: You need the LINQ Dynamic Query Library ( http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx ) for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like 
        results.Where(i=>(i.Name+"").ToString().ToUpper().Contains("ap".ToUpper())))

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
var z = RadGrid2.MasterTableView.FilterExpression;
            string filter = "";
            if (z.Split('\"').Length > 3)
            {
                string v = "'" + z.Split('\"')[3] + "'";
                string c = z.Split('\"')[0];
                string opr = " like ";
                c = c.Replace("(iif(", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("==", "").Replace("null", "").Replace(",", "");

                filter = c + opr + v ;
            }
            else
                filter = z;


            e.InputParameters["filterExpression"] = filter;
```